# Passing failed notebook Error to outside of "Execute Pipeline" in Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

So, I have an "Execute Pipeline" in ADF and inside of it I have multiples notebook's that are writing queries to tables.

I also a databricks notebook with a class for sending e-mails (that notebook receives dynamically, using widget's, the error, and this error is what is going to be send as the body of the e-mail)

Well, currently I have this working: if a notebook fails, the entire "Execute Pipeline" fails. Now, I what I want to do is if a notebook fails, it goes to the e-mail notebook with the error and it sends an e-mail.

I tried this:
[image]

The parameter that I am giving the notebook error is:

[image]

It does work, but it clutters the pipeline to much!

Ideally, I would like something like this, but I am having trouble passing the error of the failed notebook from inside the "Execute Pipeline" to the outside.

[image]

Does anybody knows how can I do this? Or have a different way? I was also thinking about a Try-Catch inside the pipeline but I am not sure it would work :/

Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass value from one pipeline to activity of the other pipeline, you can use pipeline return value option in set variable activity.

- Click the `Wait on completion` in the execute pipeline activity.

[image]

- In the pipeline, which is invoked through execute pipeline activity, add a set variable activity and create a new variable and define the variable. Here, I created a variable called `return_val` and notebook output is given as value for that variable.

[image]

- In the main pipeline after execute activity, you can add any activity and you can pass the value from child pipeline.

`@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.return_val`

Here `return_val` is the variable name that I used in the child pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I just have a little question, on your second picture I understood what you are doing, but I am trying to have a similar thought for my invoked pipeline (that is my first picture - without the e-mails), what would you recommend in this case? Because I have a lot of notebook's activity inside the "Execute pipelien" and if one notebook fails I want to send that message to outside

Comment: You can create many pipeline return variables in the invoked pipeline. Means, you can store any number of values that needs to be passed to main pipeline using set variable activity.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a "cleaner" way of doing it?

Comment: Could you explain what `cleaner way` means?

Comment: I meant without putting return variables in all notebook's in case of a fail in the invoked pipeline

Comment: you can connect one set variable activity with all the notebook activities. You can create multiple variables there. [img](https://i.imgur.com/tWsfome.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254837/discussion-between-aswin-and-ines-silva).